# How to get the values from controller to view

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I prepare one list i controller i want to pas the list value to view in view i have dynamic table which was created in j query

My controller code is

```
public JsonResult GetTimeTable()
    {
        List<StudentViewModel> list = new List<StudentViewModel>();
        list= studentServices.studentdata();
        return this.Json(
         new {list=list },JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

and my view code is

```
function GetTimeTable() { 
var URL = '@Url.Action("GetTimeTable", "StudentDetails")';
$.ajax({        
   url: URL,
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    type: "GET",
    dataType: "json",       
    success: function (data) {
        debugger
        var details;
        $("#dynamictable").append('<table id="table"></table>')
        var table = $("#dynamictable").children();
        table.append("<tr><th>Name</th><th>Age</th><th>Marks1</th><th>Marks2</th><th>Marks3</th></tr>");
        var row = table.append("<tr><td>Name</td><td>Age</td><td>Marks1</td><td>Marks2</td><td>Marks3</td></tr>");          
        alert('Data is inserted Sucessfully');
    },
    error: function (data) {
        alert('Data is not present ');
    }
});
}
```

Comment: The parameter `data` contains a property named `list` which is the collection returned by your method. Use `$.each(data.list, function(index, item) { ..` to loop through the items

Comment: @Stephen Muecke List values are  not coming to table row what i have to edit in table row  as i show in my view code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your not using the data you have returned to build the table. Unless you need to return additional data, I suggest you simplify you method to

```
public JsonResult GetTimeTable()
{
    return Json(studentServices.studentdata(), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

In the success function, `data` contains the collection which you need to access in a loop (after appending the table header). Note this assumes `StudentViewModel` contains properties `Name`, `Age`, `Mark1` etc.

```
$.each(data, function(index, item) {
  var row = $('<tr></tr>');
  row.append($('<td></td>').text(item.Name));
  row.append($('<td></td>').text(item.Age));
  row.append($('<td></td>').text(item.Mark1));
  // ... other table columns
  table.append(row);
});
```

**Edit**

Further to the comments, your `studentdata()` method need to be amended as follows

```
public List<StudentViewModel> studentdata() 
{ 
  // StudentViewModel studentViewModel = new StudentViewModel(); 
  List<StudentViewModel> list = new List<StudentViewModel>(); 
  SqlParameter[] parameters=new SqlParameter[0]; 
  DataSet dataset = DataHelper.ExecuteAdapter(CommandType.StoredProcedure,"sp_GetStudentData", parameters); 
  DataTable dataTable = dataset.Tables[0]; 
  for (int i = 0; i < dataTable.Rows.Count; i++) 
  {
    StudentViewModel studentViewModel = new StudentViewModel(); // add this
    studentViewModel.Name = dataTable.Rows[i]["Name"].ToString(); 
    studentViewModel.Age = Convert.ToInt16(dataTable.Rows[i]["Age"]); 
    studentViewModel.Marks1 = Convert.ToInt16(dataTable.Rows[i]["Marks1"]); 
    studentViewModel.Marks2 = Convert.ToInt16(dataTable.Rows[i]["Marks2"]); 
    studentViewModel.Marks3 = Convert.ToInt16(dataTable.Rows[i]["Marks3"]); 
    list.Add(studentViewModel); 
  } 
  return list; 
}
```

Comment: Same column values  is repeating i have different values of diff columns

Comment: I don't understand you comment - the code is looping each `StudentViewModel` in your collection so if the rows are being repeated, then each `StudentViewModel` has the same values

Comment: Only first values is repeating in all the rows in table

Comment: Still not sure what you mean. Add `console.log(item);` in the first line of the loop and debug it to see what data your receiving.

Comment: You need to post your model (I just guessed what you property names might be) And have you deleted the line `var row = table.append("<tr><td>Name ....` (which you need to).

Comment: Then that what your method `studentServices.studentdata()` is returning! Debug your server method to check.

Comment: I have added the necessary corrections to your `studentdata()` as per chat.

Answer (score 0):

You can Get Data From Success Function ..like This

var testdata=data.list;

Answer (score 0):

The 'data' is of a type list and you have to loop through that list in order to display the table content.

Answer (score 0):

As you are returning the data as form of list and name of the property is list it self so the code will look like this

```
          success : function(result){
                   $.each(result.list,function(idx,item){
                      // now the item is each row from your data sent by the controller.
                    html.append('<tr><td>' + item.Marks + '</td></tr>';
                   } 
          }
```